# Webpack Mix isn't Updating Files in Laravel 5.6

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.6, laravel-mix

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/frontend/app.scss', 'public/css/frontend.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/backend/app.scss', 'public/css/backend.css')
    .styles([
        'public/js/select2/select2.css',
        'public/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'public/css/custom-style.css',
    ], 'public/css/backend-custom.css')
    .js([
        'resources/assets/js/backend/app.js',
        'resources/assets/js/plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/plugins.js'
    ], 'public/js/backend.js')
    .scripts([
        "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
        "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js",
        "public/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
    ], 'public/js/backend-custom.js')
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new WebpackRTLPlugin('/css/[name].rtl.css')
        ]
    })
    .version();
```

I also tried with no luck: `npm run watch-poll`.

**PHP version: 7.2.4

Laravel: 5.6.26

Node: 10.9.0 

NPM: 6.4.0**

Comment: What is the error that you received while running `npm run dev` || `npm run watch` ?

Comment: There is no any error while running those commands. Checked log file also but There is nothing.

Comment: That is complete strange behavior. In the terminal, you should see some output, regardless of error or no error.